# Equality of values doesn't carry over to types depending on those values; am I missing something?

Tags: dependent-type, idris

I'm trying to implement as much of System F (polymorphic lambda calculus) as I can in Idris. I'm now faced with a problem that I want to demonstrate with an example:

```
data Foo = Bar Nat

Eq Foo where
 (Bar _) == (Bar _) = True

data Baz: Foo -> Type where
 Quux: (n: Nat) -> Baz (Bar n)

Eq (Baz f) where
 (Quux a) == (Quux b) = ?todo
```

As you can see, any two `Foo` values are equal. I would now like to be able to use this fact while defining equality on `Baz f`: `Quux a` has type `Baz (Foo a)`, `Quux b` has type `Baz (Foo b)`, and `Foo a` and `Foo b` are equal, so my intuition is that this should work. But the compiler refuses it, saying there's a type mismatch between `Baz (Foo a)` and `Baz (Foo b)`.

Is there a way to make this work? This issue is stopping me from implementing alpha equivalence.

Comment: My advice is [_not to implement alpha equivalence_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_index)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I am mostly ignorant of system F and alpha equivalence, so take this with a grain of salt. However, one way to fix your problem **in the particular situation you posted** is this:

```
data Foo = Bar

bar: Nat -> Foo
bar _ = Bar

Eq Foo where
 Bar == Bar = True

data Baz: Foo -> Type where
 Quux: (n: Nat) -> Baz (bar n)

Eq (Baz f) where
 (Quux a) == (Quux b) = ?todo
```

As far as I understand it, `Eq` instances are for equality checks at **runtime**. They are not consulted to check whether two types unify.

You want all `Foo` instances to unify on the type level, so there can actually only be one; let's just call it `Bar`. The data constructor of that name, that you had in your code, was relegated to a function `bar`, that just returns the unique `Foo` instance `Bar` for every `Nat`.

The `Eq` implementation for `Foo` is even more trivial now (although it is no longer needed in this case) and `Quux` now uses `bar` instead `Bar`, so all the `Baz` instances created by it really share the same type `Baz Foo`.

Answer (score 1):

Why not define another operator for heterogenous equality and use that instead ?

```
module Main

infix 5 ~=

interface HEq a b where
  (~=) : a -> b -> Bool

-- This will make ~= work as replacement for ==
Eq a => HEq a a where
  (~=) = (==)

data Foo = Bar Nat

Eq Foo where
  (Bar _) == (Bar _) = True

data Baz : Foo -> Type where
  Quux : (n : Nat) -> Baz (Bar n)

HEq (Baz a) (Baz b) where
  (Quux x) ~= (Quux y) = True -- do whatever you want here

main : IO Unit
main = do
  putStrLn $ show $ 5 ~= 5 -- prints True
  putStrLn $ show $ 5 ~= 6 -- prints False
  putStrLn $ show $ (Quux 10) ~= (Quux 20) -- prints True
```